# How to make an Array or Map return a variable(and not the value of it)

Tags: arrays, kotlin, variables

I have a program that I got off a tutorial that uses an if chain, and I wanted to see if I could optimize it.
My first thought was using a map but it doesn't pass the variable, just the value of the variable.

Is there any alternative ways to do this?

If not, it's fine, I just wanted to know if this was possible.

I would like to see if it is possible to have something like this

```
var map = mapOf(value1 to variable1, value2 to variable2)
map[value1] = true // variable1 becomes true
```

Comment: It is very unclear what you're asking about. Maybe you can share some example code to illustrate what you're trying to do?

Comment: I added something, hope this clears things up

Comment: Are you looking for `mutableMapOf`? I don't see what your code has to do with whatever it is you're describing in the first paragraph. Do you mean you want to store references to some `var` properties (not the values of those properties) so you can change what those properties return by accessing them from the map?

Comment: from the little context we have, I think you should use classes

Comment: I posted an answer, but it really seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Could you provide an example of this code with "if chains" that you try to optimize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we need to reference values by dynamic names, then the usual solution is to simply use a map and not represent individual values as local variables.

In Kotlin we can use [delegated properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html) in a way that looks like we store local variables in a map:

```kotlin
val map = mutableMapOf<String, Int>()
var variable1 by map
var variable2 by map

variable1 = 5
variable2 = 7
println(variable1) // 5
map["variable1"] = 10
println(variable1) // 10
```

This is a little different than what you asked for, but the result is pretty similar: we can reference values both by the local var and by the name/key.

Another solution is to create a small wrapper around your value. Then if you acquire it from the map and modify its stored value, it will change in other places as well.

Answer (score 1):

Without more context, it's hard to determine what you really need. I think you should use classes for this.
For example,

```kotlin
    data class BooleanWrapper(var value:Boolean)
    var map = mapOf(value1 to BooleanWrapper(false), value2 to BooleanWrapper(true))
    println(map[value1]?.value) // print false
    map[value1]!!.value = true 
    println(map[value1]?.value) // print true
```